# Can Hogwarts prefects dock points or not?

Tags: harry-potter

In *The Chamber of Secrets*, Percy - a Gryffindor prefect - docks 5 points from Harry, Ron and Hermione for lurking in a girls' bathroom. In *The Order of the Phoenix*, however, Draco states that prefects cannot in fact dock points from students:

> I know prefects can’t dock points, Weasel King. But members of the Inquisitorial Squad –

I'm just a bit confused. Is this just sloppy writing or did the rules change?

Comment: Wasn't Percy Head Prefect ?

Comment: @Kalissar Percy was not Headboy in Chamber of Secrets, but he was in Prisoner of Azkaban

Answer (score -2):

**EDITED**
Draco's comment does come across as a slight contradiction but maybe prefects could not dock points from fellow prefects in OOTP, i.e. Hermione and Ron? 
there is another instance that I need to double check but didn't the Fred and George lock Marcus Flint (ok, Marcus was part of the Inquisitorial Squad) in the vanishing cabinet because he was about to dock points from them too? (I think this was also in OOTP)

[Duplicate of Question - Can prefects take points from houses](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/can-prefects-take-points-from-houses)

Comment: Ron & Hermione are not Prefects till OOTP

Comment: yes I am talking about the contradiction in Draco and Ron's comments re docking points when they are both prefects. I was not referring to R&H being prefects in CoS