# Has Snape ever given points to Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter

Has Professor Snape ever given points to Gryffindor? I couldn't find anything like this in books.

Comment: Has Professor Snape ever given points...?

Comment: @phyrfox - He has not

Answer (score 105, accepted):

As you can see from this [handy chart on the HP Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/House_points) (and this rather more [detailed list](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/house-points-1991-1992/) on the HP Lexicon) Professor Snape not only failed to award a *Gryffindor* a single point, he failed to award ***anyone*** a single point.

[Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/a-handy-history-of-hogwarts-house-points-infographic) has a nice infographic showing the breakdown of point distribution in the novels. As you can see, the flow of votes only runs one way where Prof. Snape is concerned.

[image]

Comment: What a grumpy sod.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I could never work out why he didn't stand up at the end of Philosopher's Stone and give Malfoy a million points for eating his dinner nicely.

Comment: @Edlothiad - The lexicon seems to have a better list; https://www.hp-lexicon.org/thing/house-points-1991-1992/. I think the infographic is probably confusing Neville's 50 point gain for a loss.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that such infographic exists...

Comment: Huh? How come he never awarded points to Slytherin?

Comment: @Worse_Username - Probably he did, just off-screen. Don't forget that literally thousands of points were awarded that we don't see.

Comment: An interesting corollary is that Dumbledore failed to deduct any points.

Comment: @jpmc - And that the most even-handed professor was Umbridge

Comment: @Valorum - note that Umbridge handed out detentions like candy, so maybe that's why she appeared "even-handed" with regards to points.

Comment: Wait... Draco took points?  Did I forget that that prefects can take points? (percy is there.)

Comment: I'm shocked that Professor Sprout never gave Neville points in narrative considering what a good herbology student he was.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Prefects couldn't, even under Umbridge, but the 'Inquisitorial Squad' could.

Comment: @owjburnham Prefects could - Percy did - until they couldn't (or both Ron and Draco forgot that they could, take your pick).

Comment: @PaulL I hadn't realised until today how many edits had been made between different editions of the books!

Comment: @kaine see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12189/4918 "Can prefects take points from houses?"

Comment: What do all the asterisks mean?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Where the number requires explanation, for example Harry, Neville and Ron all lost one point *between them*, hence 1/3. Crabbe and Goyle were caught loitering and fined one point, hence 1/2

Comment: @Valorum Oh. Okay. I knew that they required explanation, but the explanations are not listed.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Because I cropped the image for readability; https://www.pottermore.com/features/a-handy-history-of-hogwarts-house-points-infographic

Comment: @Valorum I see that now